# Date range for unique values in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a table in Excel that looks like this (as a minimum viable product):

```
ID       Date
-------  --------------
1        10/5/1984
1        10/5/1985
1        10/5/1986
2        10/5/1984
2        10/5/1985
3        10/5/1984
```

The aim is to output only those IDs that have a >= 2 year period, with the aim of deleting every ID from the list that doesn't cover a 2 year poriod. What would be the best way to do that?

Example results would be:

```
ID       >= 2 Years?
-------  --------------
1        Yes
2        No
3        No
```

but really any way that does it is OK, I don't know how to do it for each unique ID.

This is my first time posting so do please let me know if I need to provide more information, thank you!

Comment: What kind of overall date range are you looking at? (Note that Excel doesn't handle pre-1900 dates very nicely.)

Comment: Those dates were made up, all the actual dates are from the last 25 years. I think the oldest date was from 1990, does that answer what you wanted?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. If you needed to work with older dates, it would be more difficult. I'd suggest editing the post to update the dates the 1980's instead of the 1880's to keep the answers just related to what you are interested in rather than dealing with older dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two formulas will do what you want:

The array formula:

```
=IF(DATEDIF(MIN(IF($A$2:$A$7=E2,$B$2:$B$7)),MAX(IF($A$2:$A$7=E2,$B$2:$B$7)),"Y")>=2,"YES","NO")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly the Excel will put '{}' Around the formula.

Non CSE formula (Entered normally):

```
=IF(DATEDIF(AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$7/($A$2:$A$7=E2),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$7/($A$2:$A$7=E2),1),"y")>=2,"YES","NO")
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! Really impressed you bust that out so quickly, appreciate it a lot.